# While loop Mysql updating checkboxes where to start

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a question how can I update the database if person unchecks or check a checkbox and update the boolean field
 in mysql? For days stuck with this problem, because problem I don't know how to make a form or check if
it is validate inside of a while loop here is my code:

```
<?
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars");
    $counter = 1;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $counter++ . '</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"';  
            if ($row['show'] == true) {  
                echo 'checked></td>'; 
            } else { 
                echo 'unchecked></td>'; 
            }
            echo '<td><img src="../xml/'.$row['cars_id'].'-1.JPG"  width="120px"></td>';        
            echo "<td><h3> ", $row['brand']," " . $row['model'], " " . $row['type'], 
             " &euro; " . $row['price'], " </h3></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

p.s. I am aware of the mysql to mysqli or pdo but it is a HUGE script...

Comment: Do you want it to dynamically update the DB? Like, as soon as a user clicks the checkbox, it will update the DB, without the user having to submit a form? If so, you'll have to use Javascript to add a listener to the checkbox, and onchange make an AJAX call to a PHP script that will execute the SQL to update the DB. Javascript libraries like jquery make adding listeners and executing ajax calls a lot more streamlined and simple.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: Take a look at @CoderSam's answer. I would also do some research into using the jquery library, and how to use it to "listen" to a form element, and how to send an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! No issue here is the solution:
Try using jquery and ajax. For example.

```
if (  $("#chkbx").prop('checked') == true) {
    // do ajax call to update the database
} else {
    // do anything if check box is unchecked
}
```

I am not writing the ajax call just see the jquery ajax manual.  If you face any problem come back.

See the above code will create a event listener in the DOM so that when the check box is checked a event should fire.
Now I am extending my code to show you a ajax call.

```
if (  $("#chkbx").prop('checked') == true) {
    $.ajax ({
        method: "POST", // type:post or get
        url: "test.php", // your php file
        data: { name: "test"} // data that I want to send
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); // after success show msg
    })
}
```

Now in the php file do the updating part of database or anything you want. The done function will show the msg you returned if the php file execute properly. There are numerous functions in ajax that you can use.Also try to use jquery it's handy and easy to use.

Comment: Edited my answer for more clarity.

Comment: hey CoderSam, thanks a million! One more question actualy my last one too... How can I send it the the test.php file that part it is not doing it does work but the ID of the checkbox is not sending (check my code bellow how far I came)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, now I only have to focus on how database works in Ajax

This is what I added and with this I can echo out that it does work now what rest is change the boolean value row['show']

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function change_checkbox(el){
    if(el.checked){
        alert("On");
    }else{
        alert("Off");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got pretty far that all is working except for 1 particulair thing.

The problem what I now face is that I cannot send the DATA ID's from the checkbox to the test.php page how can I do this correct this is what I came up with so far:

```
    <?
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars");
$counter = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $counter++ . '</td>
            <td><input id="'.$row['cars_id'].'" onchange="change_checkbox(this)" type="checkbox"';  
            if ($row['toon'] == true){  
                echo 'checked></td>'; 
            }else 
            { 
            echo 'unchecked></td>'; 
        }
    echo '<td><img src="../xml/'.$row['cars_id'].'-1.JPG"  width="120px"></td>';        
    echo "<td><h3> ", $row['brand']," " . $row['model'], " " . $row['type'], " &euro; " . $row['price'], " </h3></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function change_checkbox(el){
    var id = null;
    if(el.checked){             
        alert("On");
            $.ajax ({
            method: "POST", // type:post or get
            url: "test.php", // your php file
            data: { id: id } // data that I want to send
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); // after success show msg
        })          
    }else{
        alert("Off");
            $.ajax ({
            method: "POST", // type:post or get
            url: "test.php", // your php file
            data: { name: "test"} // data that I want to send
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); // after success show msg
        })
    }
    }
```